# FileProvider include all subfolders

Tags: android

I have a FileProvider working just perfectly well and I'm able to share the files to any applications, here is my code:

FilePaths.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
   <!-- choose between cache-path (cache storage), files-path (app-private storage) and  external-path (external storage) -->
   <cache-path path="/" name="strips" />
</paths>
```

Setting the share intent:

```
     File f = new File(_fileFullName);

     var contentUri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(this,
        G.FileProviderAuthorityName,
        f);
     intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, contentUri);

     _shareProvider.SetShareIntent(intent);
```

This works extremely well. I forgot to mention here that my file is usually within a subfolder of app cache directory, it works regardless no matter where they are (folders are created dynamically).

However when I change xml from cache-path to files-path (AppPrivate storage) I get IllegalArgumentException:

> Failed to find configured root that contains
>   /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/app.namespace/files/subfolder/data.png on the GetUriForFile call.

I've tried all the variations in FilePaths.xml, googled all I could and couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Please ignore, found my problem. I used getExternalFilesDir(null) instead of getFilesDir() to save my files.

Fixed that by reading android support library source code. Internally getUriForFile executes this code to decide which directory to use:

```
 File target = null;
                if (TAG_ROOT_PATH.equals(tag)) {
                    target = buildPath(DEVICE_ROOT, path);
                } else if (TAG_FILES_PATH.equals(tag)) {
                    target = buildPath(context.getFilesDir(), path);
                } else if (TAG_CACHE_PATH.equals(tag)) {
                    target = buildPath(context.getCacheDir(), path);
                } else if (TAG_EXTERNAL.equals(tag)) {
                    target = buildPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), path);
                }
```

The chooses the closest matching path from the XML definition, meaning that subfolders will have no problems:

```
// Find the most-specific root path
            Map.Entry<String, File> mostSpecific = null;
            for (Map.Entry<String, File> root : mRoots.entrySet()) {
                final String rootPath = root.getValue().getPath();
                if (path.startsWith(rootPath) && (mostSpecific == null
                        || rootPath.length() > mostSpecific.getValue().getPath().length())) {
                    mostSpecific = root;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Just fell into the same trap. You saved me probably an hour of debugging.